# What's a good pattern to manage impossible states in Elm?

Tags: graph, functional-programming, elm

Maybe you can help. I'm an Elm beginner and I'm struggling with a rather mundane problem. I'm quite excited with Elm and I've been rather successful with smaller things, so now I tried something more complex but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

I'm trying to build something in Elm that uses a graph-like underlying data structure. I create the graph with a fluent/factory pattern like this:

```
sample : Result String MyThing
sample =
  MyThing.empty
    |> addNode 1 "bobble"
    |> addNode 2 "why not"
    |> addEdge 1 2 "some data here too"
```

When this code returns `Ok MyThing`, then the whole graph has been set up in a consistent manner, guaranteed, i.e. all nodes and edges have the required data and the edges for all nodes actually exist.

The actual code has more complex data associated with the nodes and edges but that doesn't matter for the question. Internally, the nodes and edges are stored in the `Dict Int element`.

```
type alias MyThing =
  { nodes : Dict Int String
  , edges : Dict Int { from : Int, to : Int, label : String } 
  }
```

Now, in the users of the module, I want to access the various elements of the graph. But whenever  I access one of the nodes or edges with `Dict.get`, I get a `Maybe`. That's rather inconvenient because by the virtue of my constructor code I *know* the indexes exist etc. I don't want to clutter upstream code with `Maybe` and `Result` when I *know* the indexes in an edge exist. To give an example:

```
getNodeTexts : Edge -> MyThing -> Maybe (String, String)
getNodeTexts edge thing =
  case Dict.get edge.from thing.nodes of
    Nothing ->
      --Yeah, actually this can never happen...
      Nothing
    Just fromNode -> case Dict.get edge.to thing.nodes of
      Nothing -> 
        --Again, this can never actually happen because the builder code prevents it.
        Nothing
      Just toNode ->
        Just ( fromNode.label, toNode.label )
```

That's just a lot of boilerplate code to handle something I specifically prevented in the factory code. But what's even worse: Now the consumer needs extra boilerplate code to handle the `Maybe`--potentially not knowing that the `Maybe` will actually *never* be `Nothing`. The API is sort of lying to the consumer. Isn't that something Elm tries to avoid? Compare to the hypothetical but incorrect:

```
getNodeTexts : Edge -> MyThing -> (String, String)
getNodeTexts edge thing =
  ( Dict.get edge.from thing.nodes |> .label
  , Dict.get edge.to thing.nodes |> .label 
  )
```

An alternative would be not to use `Int` IDs but use the actual data instead--but then updating things gets very tedious as connectors can have many edges. Managing state without the decoupling through `Int`s just doesn't seem like a good idea.

I feel there must be a solution to this dilemma using opaque ID types but I just don't see it. I would be very grateful for any pointers.

Note: I've also tried to use both `drathier` and `elm-community` elm-graph libraries but they don't address the specific question. They rely on `Dict` underneath as well, so I end up with the same `Maybe`s.

Comment: You can return `("No Edge", "No MyThing")` on the sad paths. The return type is then `(String, String)` and everybody is happy. It is a bit kludgy but does the job.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Thanks for the suggestion. That's what I'm currently doing. I agree that it's ok from a pragmatic point of view because those conditions cannot occur, so who cares... but as you say, it's a bit kludgy, especially since my data structures are not just strings. I have to create a `dummyNode` and `dummyEdge` function with NaNs as certain values etc. Maybe it's just a limitaiton of static type inference. I dunno.

Comment: The core issue is that a graph can be defined recursively but cannot be constructed recursively. While a tree can be constructed recursively and can avoid functions with `Maybe` results, functions on a graph cannot, because graph representations require indirection. In your case, the indirection is accomplished with using integer keys in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it looks to me like those states actually aren't impossible.

Let's start with your definition of `MyThing`:

```
type alias MyThing =
  { nodes : Dict Int String
  , edges : Dict Int { from : Int, to : Int, label : String } 
  }
```

This is a type alias, not a type – meaning the compiler will accept `MyThing` in place of `{nodes : Dict Int String, edges : Dict Int {from : Int, to : Int, label : String}}` and vice-versa.

So rather than construct a `MyThing` value safely using your factory functions, I can write:

```
import Dict
myThing = { nodes = Dict.empty, edges = Dict.fromList [(0, {from = 0, to = 1, label = "Edge 0"})] }
```

… and then pass `myThing` to any of your functions expecting `MyThing`, even though the nodes connected by *Edge 0* aren't contained in `myThing.nodes`.

You can fix this by changing `MyThing` to be a custom type:

```
type MyThing
    = MyThing { nodes : Dict Int String
              , edges : Dict Int { from : Int, to : Int, label : String } 
              }
```

… and exposing it using `exposing (MyThing)` rather than `exposing (MyThing(..))`. That way, no constructor for `MyThing` is exposed, and code outside of your module must use the factory functions to obtain a value.

The same applies to `Edge`, wich I'm assuming is defined as:

```
type alias Edge =
    { from : Int, to : Int, label : String }
```

Unless it is changed to a custom type, it is trivial to construct arbitrary `Edge` values:

```
type Edge
    = Edge { from : Int, to : Int, label : String }
```

Then however, you will need to expose some functions to obtain `Edge` values to pass to functions like `getNodeTexts`. Let's assume I have obtained a `MyThing` and one of its edges:

```
myThing : MyThing
-- created using factory functions

edge : Edge
-- an edge of myThing
```

Now I create another `MyThing` value, and pass it to `getNodeTexts` along with `edge`:

```
myOtherThing : MyThing
-- a different value of type MyThing

nodeTexts = getNodeTexts edge myOtherThing
```

This should return `Maybe.Nothing` or `Result.Err String`, but certainly not `(String, String)` – the edge does not belong to `myOtherThing`, so there is no guarantee its nodes are contained in it.

Comment: I can't see how - inside the MyThing module - you won't have the same issue as OP noted - Maybe values even though things have been built using reliable helpers

Comment: You're completely right – inside the module, there is no way around that. It is a price paid for using the Dict type.

Comment: I agree that using proper ("opaque") types is better than type aliases. I'm actually fine to handle the `Maybe`s inside the module. I just don't want them to leak into the consumer code. One idea I came up with is to maintain the context inside the opaque types, in a manner of speaking: `type Edge = Edge { id : Int, thing : MyThing }` meaning, there is an ID that is valid within the context of that thing. That way, the `Int` is never exposed and the guarantees are actually working. Any thoughts? Is this a good design? It will still require to have a dummy response internally.

Comment: @Hasko I'm not sure I see the benefit of that, but I don't know your API and use cases. To give better advice, imo we would need to see quite a bit more code. This may be better suited to the CodeReview SE – if you like, you can ask a question there with your full API and enough code for a review.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy answer to your question. I can offer one comment and a coding suggestion.

You use the magic words "impossible state" but as OOBalance has pointed out, you can create an impossible state in your modelling. The normal meaning of "impossible state" in Elm is precisely in relation to modelling e.g. when you use two `Bool`s to represent 3 possible states. In Elm you can use a custom type for this and not leave one combination of bools in your code.

As for your code, you can reduce its length (and perhaps complexity) with

```
getNodeTexts : Edge -> MyThing -> Maybe ( String, String )
getNodeTexts edge thing =
    Maybe.map2 (\ n1 n2  -> ( n1.label, n2.label ))
        (Dict.get edge.from thing.nodes)
        (Dict.get edge.to thing.nodes)
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. Indeed that code is simpler--I'm still a beginner. As you noted in another comment, it does not solve the problem of "leaky Maybe" but I'm still glad to learn a better way of writing my code.